# How do I unit test my request, given that the return result is always encrypted?

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, encryption, sinon

I have this helper class that helps to generate request header and return it as a `request.SuperAgentRequest` using `superagent-bluebird-promise`.

My question here is

How do I unit test my request? Given that the return result is always encrypted.

**How to test `security.decryptJWE`?**

What I have done in my unit testing so far is to only check the number of times the function is being called.

Unit test class:

```
let sendRequestSpy = sinon.spy(helper, "sendRequest");

main.updateInfo();

sinon.assert.callCount(sendRequestSpy, 10);
```

helper class:

```
const restClient = require('superagent-bluebird-promise');

function sendRequest(id) {
    ...

    _.set(headers, "Authorization", authHeaders);

    let request = restClient.get(url);

    // Set headers
    if (!_.isUndefined(headers) && !_.isEmpty(headers)) {
        request.set(headers);
    }

    return request;
}
```

main class:

```
function updateInfo {

    ...
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {

            let request = helper.sendRequest(id);
            request.buffer(true).end(function (err, res) {
            ...
                let data = {
                    body: res.body,
                    text: res.text
                };

                let apiData = data.text;

                let privateKey = "./resource/priv_key.pem";

                var jweParts = apiData.split(".");
                security.decryptJWE(jweParts[0], jweParts[1], jweParts[2], jweParts[3], jweParts[4], privateKey)
                .then(apiData => {
                    ...
                    //process here
                }
            }
    }
}
```

security class:

```
...
security.decryptJWE = function decryptJWE(header, encryptedKey, iv, cipherText, tag, privateKey) {
  console.log("Decrypting JWE".green + " (Format: " + "header".red + "." + "encryptedKey".cyan + "." + "iv".green + "." + "cipherText".magenta + "." + "tag".yellow + ")");
  console.log(header.red + "." + encryptedKey.cyan + "." + iv.green + "." + cipherText.magenta + "." + tag.yellow);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    var keystore = jose.JWK.createKeyStore();

    console.log((new Buffer(header, 'base64')).toString('ascii'));

    var data = {
      "type": "compact",
      "ciphertext": cipherText,
      "protected": header,
      "encrypted_key": encryptedKey,
      "tag": tag,
      "iv": iv,
      "header": JSON.parse(jose.util.base64url.decode(header).toString())
    };
    keystore.add(fs.readFileSync(privateKey, 'utf8'), "pem")
      .then(function (jweKey) {
        // {result} is a jose.JWK.Key
        jose.JWE.createDecrypt(jweKey)
          .decrypt(data)
          .then(function (result) {
            resolve(JSON.parse(result.payload.toString()));
          })
          .catch(function (error) {
            reject(error);
          });
      });

  })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error("Error with decrypting JWE: %s".red, error);
      throw "Error with decrypting JWE";
    })
}
```

Comment: What is security.decryptJWE?

Comment: @estus I modify my question to include the module. It is just a class to decrypt response.

Comment: I cannot say anything about request because it's unclear what you test; there's no updateInfo. But every unit but tested one should be mocked or stubbed. If updateInfo involves decryptJWE, mock decryptJWE in one test and test it directly in another.

Answer (score 0):

After much research, I finally managed to find out how to test my request.

and that is using nocks.

```
let test = nock('https://test.api.com/id')
        .get('/ID123945/')
        .reply(200, json.encoded.success.result);
```

However, i am still unable to find out how to test with the return data (of my own and return it as encrypted)